# Change Password Plugin is not working in roundcube

Tags: roundcube, directadmin

I have installed roundcube manually in a cpanel based server. I have added and enabled Password Plugin. But while trying to change password after login i am getting the following error :

```
Could not save new password. Can't create socket connection to tcp://localhost:2222
```

I tried to change tcp:// to ssl:// and localhost to my domain host but none is working.

Comment: Is is `tls://`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right. If you are using directadmin over SSL, this should work:

```
$config['password_directadmin_host'] = 'ssl://localhost';
```

If you have changed the default port used by DA, you should also change the port number here:

```
$config['password_directadmin_port'] = 2222;
```

If that's all good, be sure to check the password driver is set correct:

```
$config['password_driver'] = 'directadmin';
```

Still not working? Check the logs and paste it here please.